# Flow (INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY)

Tags: visual-workflow, leads

I have a flow that creates a Lead, Sales Task, Campaign Member Record and a Note. When logged in as an Administrator the flow works perfectly fine. (See below image)

When I log in as the User to test the flow I get an "INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY" error. I confirmed that the user can create all these records manually. I added a Screen element that just asks the user to click Next after it creates the Lead AND IT WORKS (as the user)?!?! The only difference between the flow not working and working is the screen element after creating the Lead.

The issue here is that if we continue persisting the Lead record and the rest of the Flow fails we'll have an orphaned Lead. Does anyone understand why the lead needs to be persisted when making relationships via the flow? [image: Flow Screen]

Comment: Are you populating a lookup record on lead?

Comment: No, There's no Lookup on the Lead. I'm creating the Lead then passing the ID of the Lead on to the Other Create Elements.